# Remove checked property on a checkbox

Tags: jquery

I have this form:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" name="item1" value="true" checked> Item 1
    </label>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" name="item2" value="true"> Item 1
    </label>
</div>
```

And this JS:

```
$.(".checkbox input[type='checkbox']").each(function() {
    if ($.(this).is(":checked")) {
        $.(this).closest(".checkbox").addClass("checked");
        $.(this).closest(".radio").addClass("checked");
    }
});
$.(".checkbox input[type='checkbox']").bind("change", function() {
    if ($.(this).is(":checked")) {
        $.(this).closest(".checkbox").addClass("checked");
    } else {
        $.(this).closest(".checkbox").removeClass("checked");
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jze3fwdp/

---

How can I change my JS code in order to remove the `checked` property in the unchecked checkbox ?

Actually the class changed but the checked value stay in place.

Thanks.

---

I tried without success:

```
$.(this).prop('checked', true);
```

and

```
$.(this).closest(".checkbox > input:checkbox").prop('checked', false);
```

Comment: What does "o'clock" mean?

Comment: Note that jQuery function is `$`, not `$.`. If you remove the dot, your code works as expected: http://jsfiddle.net/jze3fwdp/1/

Comment: It means that I have active the autocorrect on my Mac. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `$.(this).closest(".checkbox").attr("checked", '');` for remote the attribute checked and 
`$.(this).closest(".checkbox").attr("checked", 'checked');` for add it.

When you use `addClass` it's add a CSS class, you want to change the attribute `checked` not touch the CSS class.

EDIT:

```
$(".checkbox input[type='checkbox']").each(function() {
    updateState($(this));
});

$(".checkbox input[type='checkbox']").on("change", function() {
    updateState($(this));
});

function updateState($input){
    if ($input.is(":checked")) {
        $input.closest(".checkbox").addClass("checked");
        $input.closest(".radio").addClass("checked");
    }
    else{
        $input.removeAttr('checked');
        $input.closest(".checkbox").removeClass("checked");
        $input.closest(".radio").removeClass("checked");
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it better with `prop` ?

Comment: Yes but sometimes i had problem with prop so i always use attr.

Comment: Sorry, i don't understand?

Comment: With your code it will ad the property into the `label` tag. I want it in the `input`.